# Save button not displaying in drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I am new in drupal. I have freshly installed drupal 9, and created a custom content type named post. Everything has been good till that creation. But When I am trying to add the content, save button is missing from newly created content type. Other content type has the save button.

I have explored druapl forums, but What I found that peoples get this type of issue in forms. But I have not installed any form module.
Currently I am using drupal 9.5.11 without any other specific module.